# Angular "as" keyword or how to use a variable in html

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-translate, angular13

I use `ngx-translate` in angular 13 and often have something like this in html

```
<div> {{ 'prefix.'+'my translation key'+'.suffix' | translate }} </div>
```

now, the question is that when that translation is empty, I don't want to display at all the `div`. I tried to use this one

```
<div *ngIf="'prefix.'+'my translation key'+'.suffix' | translate as myText && true"> 
    {{ myText }} 
</div>
```

but this does not seem to work or even compile, probably I misuse the `as` keyword. See **[here a codepen](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y5bfki?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**.

So my question is how to reuse the same constructs like `'prefix.'+'my translation key'+'.suffix' | translate` as variable in Angular's HTML templates.

I tried also to search the Angular docs for this keyword, but didn't find that information.

**PS.** After some research, it seems that any second condition in the `ngIf` brokes the "compilation"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 *ngIf="('HOME.TITLE' | translate | uppercase as titlee) && displayTitle">{{ titlee + displayTitle}}</h2>
      <label>
        {{ 'HOME.SELECT' | translate }}
        <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public displayTitle = true;
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just reverse the order of expressions. So instead of this:

```html
<h2 *ngIf="('HOME.TITLE' | translate | uppercase as title) && displayTitle">{{ title }}</h2>
```

You should do it like this:

```html
<h2 *ngIf="displayTitle && ('HOME.TITLE' | translate | uppercase) as title">{{ title }}</h2>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y5bfki-5akvff?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: this is why my question, I don't want to repeat the same long thing twice or three times

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it again?

Comment: my question is only about the HTML part, not ts one

Comment: I know, but I was able to run your code in my end, with `as myText` in `*ngIf` and `{{myText}}` in HTML. The part for `.ts` I just added as addition to the answer.

Comment: I see that works... in my project case I has one more condition in the ngIf, and then it was broken, please take a look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-y5bfki?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I made it work on that use case as well. I updated my answer. Can you update your question with full example?

Comment: I copied the example in OP... Why the inverse does work?